# Converting a SQL query into PL/SQL in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new to PL/SQL and trying to convert an SQL statement into the PL/SQL format. I have the SQL statement as:

```
SELECT StudentIDNumber
FROM Lease
INNER JOIN Invoice
ON Invoice.LeaseID = Lease.LeaseID
WHERE IsPaid = 'N';
```

How would I go about this? Any solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The query looks fine.  Have you tried it?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. There is no such thing as a "PL/SQL query". PL/SQL is **only**  used for stored procedures, functions and triggers. Anything else is simply SQL. And the query you have **is** already SQL. So to what exactly do you want to convert that?

Answer (score 2):

I think you would only need to specify your schema in Oracle and that's about it. The other syntax should be correct (provided your tables are coming from the same Schema/table):

```
SELECT StudentIDNumber
FROM PRODDATA.Lease
INNER JOIN Invoice
ON Invoice.LeaseID = Lease.LeaseID
WHERE IsPaid = 'N';
```

This document offered by Oracle also has some basic syntax changes that could prove useful to you https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E10405_01/appdev.120/e10379/ss_oracle_compared.htm

Answer (score 1):

may be try below PlSQL snippet?

```
DECLARE
   TYPE lv_student_ID IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
BEGIN
   -- assuming you are trying to find all students who have not yet paid, you can use a nested table
   SELECT StudentIDNumber
     BULK COLLECT INTO lv_student_ID
     FROM Lease INNER JOIN Invoice ON Invoice.LeaseID = Lease.LeaseID
    WHERE IsPaid = 'N';

   -- use value as you want
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (lv_student_ID.COUNT);
END;
```

Comment: Didn't work, Got an error:
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 4, column 10:
PL/SQL: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
ORA-06550: line 4, column 3:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 9, column 24:
PLS-00330: invalid use of type name or subtype name
ORA-06550: line 9, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: seems to be an aliasing issue. Add table alias name (Lease or Invoice) before StudentIDNumber or IsPaid whichever is present in both table and try?